# Как удалить неиспользуемый код миксина в nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

lighthouse показывает, что у меня есть неиспользуемый код (судя по коду - это пара моих миксинов). На сканируемой странице миксины не импортируются. Можно ли удалить неиспользуемый код, чтобы lighthouse не ругался?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, только из сканируемой страницы.
Когда в проекте больше одного `mixin` -на, уже тяжело отследить, кто им пользуется.  По этой причине в `Reactjs` убрали `mixin` -ны, а на `Vuejs3` ввели `Composition Api`.